# Most efficient way to increment a value of everything in Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I have entries that look like this:

[image: Firebase Image]

And I want to increment the `priority` field by 1 for every Item in the list of Estimates.

I can grab the estimates like this:

```
var estimates = firebase.child('Estimates');
```

After that how would I auto increment every Estimates priority by 1?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? The firebase documentation is not bad and will help you get started. This guide will take no more than a few hours and will save you toms of time: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/

Comment: Answer below. For a next question: show what you've already tried and don't include a screenshot of text. You can export the JSON from your Firebase dashboard and include is as text, which makes it easier for us to re-use in the answer (and to use while figuring out the answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way to loop over all items and increase their priority:

```
var estimatesRef = firebase.child('Estimates');
estimatesRef.once('value', function(estimatesSnapshot) {
  estimatesSnapshot.forEach(function(estimateSnapshot) {
    estimateSnapshot.ref().update({
      estimateSnapshot.val().priority + 1
    });
  });
});
```

It loops over all children of `Estimates` and increases the priority of each.

You can also combine the calls into a single `update()` call:

```
var estimatesRef = firebase.child('Estimates');
estimatesRef.once('value', function(estimatesSnapshot) {
  var updates = {};
  estimatesSnapshot.forEach(function(estimateSnapshot) {
    updates[estimateSnapshot.key+'/priority'] = estimateSnapshot.val().priority + 1;
  });
  estimatesRef.update(updates);
});
```

The performance will be similar to the first solution (Firebase is very efficient when it comes to handling multiple requests). But in the second case it will be sent a single command to the server, so it will either fail or succeed completely.

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your code-only answer? It's [in the VLQ queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10685482) but since it does attempt to answer the question (from the looks of it), it probably shouldn't be there.

Comment: Should this work on firebase 3? It appears it doesn like the estimateSnapshot.val().priority + 1 statement....

Comment: I'm pretty sure nothing about that statement changed. If you have problem, post a question with the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we can have a look.

Comment: The problem is with the `estimateSnapshot.key()`. Since firebase 3, it's not a method, it's a value. So just remove parentheses: `estimateSnapshot.key`

Answer (score 16):

**FOR FIRESTORE API ONLY, NOT FIREBASE**

**Thanks to the latest Firestore patch (March 13, 2019), you don't need to follow the other answers above.**

Firestore's FieldValue class now hosts a **increment** method that atomically updates a numeric document field in the firestore database. You can use this FieldValue sentinel with either `set` (with mergeOptions true) or `update` methods of the `DocumentReference` object.

The usage is as follows (from the official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value), this is all there is):

```
DocumentReference washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC");

// Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
washingtonRef.update("population", FieldValue.increment(50));
```

If you're wondering, it's available from version `18.2.0` of firestore. For your convenience, the Gradle dependency configuration is `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'`

> Note: Increment operations are useful for implementing counters, but
>   keep in mind that you can update a single document only once per
>   second. If you need to update your counter above this rate, see the
>   [Distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) page.

---

**EDIT 1**: `FieldValue.increment()` is purely "server" side (happens in firestore), so you don't need to expose the current value to the client(s).

**EDIT 2**: While using the admin APIs, you can use `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` for the same functionality. Thanks to @Jabir Ishaq for voluntarily letting me know about the undocumented feature.  :)

**EDIT 3**:If the target field which you want to increment/decrement is not a number or does not exist, the `increment` method sets the value to the current value! This is helpful when you are creating a document for the first time.

Comment: can I do it using admin_sdk in python?

Comment: Oh hi. I've not seen any such method in the admin-sdk. I guess you should just use `DocumentReference.update()` ([the update method](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.2.x/DocumentReference)), since you are already running your code on a trusted environment... For now, there is no `increment` method in the  admin-sdk... (as far as I searched!)

Comment: for admin sdk, there is a little change in code `admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` for reference (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin)

Comment: @JabirIshaq Hey, thanks for the reply. I checked the page at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore.FieldValue.html but couldn't find the `increment` method documentation! Is it the case that it is present but not yet updated in the web docs?  :P

Comment: @varun yes it isnt present there but i tried and amazingly it worked for me! thanx

Comment: @JabirIshaq Oh, awesome. That's nice to know! Thanks for telling us about it, I'll update my answer regarding the same!  :)