# How to increment existing number field in Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a field which indicates the number of transactions. I would like to increment it by `1` as soon as a transaction occurs. I could'nt find any method to directly execute this.

One method is to get the user first and then update the field with the received value `+ 1`, but this is too lengthy and slow.

Can anyone tell me any other feasible method?

Comment: This question has been asked a number of times - without knowing your platform it's hard to suggest a code-level answer.

Comment: Future readers, there is now an atomic `increment` method for firestore fields: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55548224/6086782

Comment: This is the JS API Method with an example: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.2.x/FieldValue#.increment

```
let documentRef = firestore.doc('col/doc');

documentRef.update(
  'counter', Firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
).then(() => {
  return documentRef.get();
}).then(doc => {
  // doc.get('counter') was incremented
});
```

Comment: I wanted to post this as an answer, however, noone seems to be willing to reopen this question. Atomic Incements were added to Cloud Firestore. [Here is the relevant Firebase blog article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html).

Answer (score 141, accepted):

Firestore now has a specific operator for this called `FieldValue.increment()`. By applying this operator to a field, the value of that field can be incremented (or decremented) as a single operation on the server.

From the Firebase documentation on [incrementing a numeric value](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value):

> ```
> var washingtonRef = db.collection('cities').doc('DC');
> ```

> ```
> // Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
> ```

```
washingtonRef.update({
    population: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(50)
});
```

So this example increments the population by 50, no matter what is current value is. If the field doesn't exist yet (or is not a number), it is set to `50` in this case.

---

If you want to decrement a number, pass a negative value to the `increment` function. For example: `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-50)`

Comment: Please update the answer. Firebase team added a solution for increments. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/03/increment-server-side-cloud-firestore.html

Comment: Good catch Hemant. I updated the answer, and reopened the question - as I have no idea why it was closed against a question about the Realtime Database.

Comment: To add to @[Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen)'s answer. It's Important to note that "In Cloud Firestore, you can only update a single document about once per second, which might be too low for some high-traffic applications.". For this scenario, take a look at [Distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/counters) from the Firestore documentation.

Comment: Of note, decrements are handled through increment as well: `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1)` will decrement the value by 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is how it appears the Firestore (kotlin) documentation:

```
val userDocRef = db.collection("users").document("doc12345")
//automatically increment by 10
washingtonRef.update("followersCount", FieldValue.increment(1))
```

to decrement simply input a negative value i.e. -1 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

You should write a cloud function that listens to the transaction, then increase the index.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/