# Firestore Deep merging in a batch

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore

When I create a new document from my API, I would like to commit (or atomically update) a statistics collection which belongs to a root projects document:

```
    const increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    let aggregation: LooseObject = {
      totalProjects: increment,
      tags: [],
      categories: [],
    }

    const project = fakeProject() // some debug func to return a dummy project object
    const projectRef = db.collection('projects').doc()
    const projectStatsRef = db.collection('projects').doc('--stats--')

    project.categories.forEach((category: string) => {
      aggregation.categories[category] = increment
    })

    project.tags.forEach((tag: string) => {
      aggregation.tags[tag] = increment
    })

    console.log(aggregation)

    const batch = db.batch()
    batch.set(projectRef, project)
    batch.set(projectStatsRef, aggregation, {
      merge: true,
    })
    batch.commit()
```

When I inspect the console, I get the following dump for my aggregation doc (this is the shape of the data that I would expect to see in the attached screenshot):

```
{
    totalProjects: NumericIncrementTransform { operand: 1 },
    tags: [
      raid: NumericIncrementTransform { operand: 1 },
      'attack-of-the-clone': NumericIncrementTransform { operand: 1 },
      'star-wars': NumericIncrementTransform { operand: 1 }
    ],
    categories: [ movie: NumericIncrementTransform { operand: 1 } ]
  }
```

However when the doc is committed to firestore, only the following structure appears (the tags and categories arrays are both empty)
[image]

From my understanding, `merge` should perform a deep merge of all nested objects.  If this is not the case, how can I achieve what I'm after?

I'm aware this type of storage is not scalable for thousnads of tags, I'm just tinkering with firestore for the first time and wanted to see how I would make this kind of thing work

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what you were expecting that's different than what you got. It might be helpful to show before and after screens, along with a screen of what you think should have happened.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated...TLDR; the categories and tags arrays are both empty, but in the console log they have values

Comment: please post a console log of the objects right before `batch.commit()`

Comment: @Kisinga I'm getting exactly the same dump

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50763231/5927361 that helps explain how to perform atomic increments, may be of some help

Comment: So, what do you expect the document to look like after the update?  Please be specific.  I see you have arrays in your fields here, and think that they just don't work the way you expect.  But without your statement of **specific** expectation, I can't tell for sure.  Right now, the question is just kind of saying "it doesn't work".

Comment: @DougStevenson my apologies if I wasn't clear.  Originally when I built this demo out, I had a `--stats--` document which had `totalProjects: COUNT` and then a count for each tag or category at the root level.  I wanted to see if I could update it so that the counts for `tags` and `categories` are nested within an array on the same document (or would I need a new collection to represent these counters?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set with merge is not really a "deep" merge in the way you're expecting.  When you pass an object with key/value pairs, Firestore will **completely overwrite** the fields specified by *each* of those keys with new data, but leave all the other fields in the document alone.  So, if you have a document with fields { a, b, c }, and you do a set-with-merge on b, then b gets completely overwritten, and the other two go unchanged.

On top of that, Firestore doesn't at all support setting specific map field values that are embedded in arrays.  Or in other words, there is no direct array item updates using array indexes.

If you must have this document structure, you will need a transaction to read the document, modify the array field in memory to appear how you want, then write the field back to the document.  Yes, it's inconvenient, but it's the only way when you have array item updates involved.

Comment: Thanks Doug, that makes a lot of sense.  Still trying to get used to this whole NoSQL world...I'll have a think about how I can restructure my store

Comment: I thought it should be deep nested, because in this bug fix they claim to have implemented it? https://github.com/mikkopaderes/mock-cloud-firestore/issues/73