# Firebase function, increment a value

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase cloud function that should increment the value of a field when a new document is created. The function executes successfully as I can see this within the firebase logs, but it doesn't increment the value of the field.

```
exports.onFileAdded = functions.firestore.document("files/{id}").onCreate(async (change, context) => {
    const file = change.data();

    const hub = await getByCollectionAndId('hubs', file.hubId);

    Firebase.firestore().collection('teams').doc(hub.teamId).set({tileCount: Firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1)}, {merge: true});
});
```

As there are no errors, and the function executes successfully, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "is does not appear to do anything" is a bit tricky to help with. Do you see if the function is getting invoked in the Cloud Functions logs? If it isn't, then the Functions code isn't going to be of much use in debugging, since it's not being run, and you'll want to look at how you trigger this code - so the write operation to Firestore fro your app.

Comment: Apologies, I have re-worded my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is:

```
Firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1)
```

You're using the operator to increment a value on the Realtime Database, but you are using it on Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they're completely separate, and the API for one doesn't apply to the other.

To fix the problem, use the `increment` operator for Firestore:

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
```

Also see my answer here: [How to increment existing number field in Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762923/how-to-increment-existing-number-field-in-cloud-firestore)

Comment: I changed it to `Firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)` and while there were no errors, it still didn't increment the number.

Comment: The capilization of `Firebase` is unusual, but I guess you might import it under that name. I recommend adding a completion listener to your `set()` call, with a `then()` and `catch()` as shown here to see if the SDK thinks the operation succeeded or failed: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document

Comment: I've added some output into the `then()` and `catch()` and the operation is successful with the output from `then()` being showing in the function logs.

Comment: Please update your question to include the latest code and its output.