# Increment existing value in firebase firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to increment existing value in [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) ?

What I am trying.

```
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("notifications")
            .document(response.getString("multicast_id"))
            .set(notificationData);
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            .collection("users")
            .document(post.userId)
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                int followers = Integer.valueOf(task.getResult().getData().get("followers").toString());
                FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                        .collection("users")
                        .document(post.userId).update("followers", followers++).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Database Structure

```
users

  - data....
  - followers(number)
```

According to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174681/9909365) function available for increment or decrement numeric field values

> Version 5.9.0 - Mar 14, 2019
>
> Added FieldValue.increment(), which can be used in update() and
>   set(..., {merge:true}) to increment or decrement numeric field values
>   safely without transactions.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Is any function available for incrementing existing value in firestore android?

Comment: It's only a matter of time until the Android SDK gets the same `FieldValue.increment()` functionality.

Comment: @DougStevenson i hope firebasae team will provide this type of features for android in next relase....

Comment: @DougStevenson Yep! I used the feature and have written an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55548224/6086782  :)

Comment: @varun thanks for pointing letest update info

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki No problem. Glad it helped, do upvote if you haven't!  :P

Comment: @varun already Upvoted

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Thanks to the latest Firestore patch (March 13, 2019)**

Firestore's FieldValue class now hosts a **increment** method that atomically updates a numeric document field in the firestore database. You can use this FieldValue sentinel with either `set` (with mergeOptions true) or `update` methods of the `DocumentReference` object.

The usage is as follows (from the official docs, this is all there is):

```
DocumentReference washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC");

// Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
washingtonRef.update("population", FieldValue.increment(50));
```

If you're wondering, it's available from version `18.2.0` of firestore. For your convenience, the Gradle dependency configuration is `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'`

> Note: Increment operations are useful for implementing counters, but
>   keep in mind that you can update a single document only once per
>   second. If you need to update your counter above this rate, see the
>   [Distributed counters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?authuser=0) page.

---

`FieldValue.increment()` is purely "server" side (happens in firestore), so you don't need to expose the current value to the client(s).

Comment: Is there a difference between `.doc()` and `.document()`?

Comment: @ColinRicardo no there is a no diffrence

Comment: document function are used to get reference of document in java and kotlin

Comment: working nice, but I'm facing an issue when firestore persistence is turned ON. is there has any solution?