# Cannot get FieldValue.increment working in Firestore emulator with Admin SDK

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am trying to get a simple atomic increase/decrease working in Firebase Cloud Functions with Firestore triggers.
To test these, I want to execute local tests with the Firestore emulator.

But I always get the error
`FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.update() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom object (found in field myfield)`

My code is as simple as following

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();

export const mytest = functions.firestore.document('my/{doc}').onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
  return perform();
});

export async function perform(): Promise<FirebaseFirestore.WriteResult> {
  const myDocRef = .... // this is a FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference

  const decrement = admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
  return myDocRef.update({
    myfield: decrement
  });
}
```

In my tests I just call the `perform` function and then I receive the above error. It's definitely the `FieldValue.increment` that causes the error because if I just put a hardcoded number instead of the `decrement` in the update call, it works (updates to that hardcoded number).

I am on Firebase CLI 7.2.1 and emulator 1.6.2 which - according to [Most efficient way to increment a value of everything in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458930/most-efficient-way-to-increment-a-value-of-everything-in-firebase/55548224#55548224) and https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1799 should support `FieldValue.increment` in the emulator.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What version of `firebase-admin` are you using?

From your description it sounds like you're calling `perform()` directly from a Node.js script. I would recommend re-working your setup to more closely match what will actually happen in production: a client will connect directly to Firestore, create a document, and your function will be triggered.

Here's an example you can run that does this:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.createItem = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  const item = await admin.firestore().collection("items").add({ addedAt: Date.now() });
  response.send(`added ${item.id}\n`);
});

const counter = admin.firestore().collection("counters").doc("items");
exports.increment = functions.firestore.document('items/{itemId}').onCreate(async (change, context) => {
  await counter.set({ total: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1) }, { merge: true });
  const current = await counter.get();
  console.log(`incremented counter to ${current.data().total}`);
});
```

The first function, `createItem`, is an HTTP trigger that adds a document to the `items/` collection. The second function is a Firestore trigger that increments a field in the `counters/items` document whenever a document is created.

When I run

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:5001/ryanpbrewster-test/us-central1/createItem
```

it creates a document and sends a response like

```
added LGOCapHSQtlXKIMEA8Do
```

This triggers the other function, which I can see in the emulator logs:

```
I function: Beginning execution of "increment"
>  incremented counter to 6

I function: Finished "increment" in ~1s
```

Comment: I am using `firebase-admin 8.3.0`. So I am using `@firebase/testing` for my mocha tests which execute against the firestore emulator which unfortunately does not support firestore triggers until now. That's the reason I extracted most of the code from the trigger function to an extra function (`perform`) that allows me to execute this `perform()` method directly from my tests until the firestore emulator supports firestore triggers. The thing is - in production my code works, it just does not work in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

**Here's some example you can use it**

```
const dbFieldValue = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

 const userPayout = Number(reward);
 transaction.update(userRef, { USER_WALLET_AMOUNT: FieldValue.increment(userPayout)});
```

**in this way it works on emulator & production**